# How to center a <div> without affecting the contents inside?

Tags: html, alignment

I am trying to make this `<div>` i have to center on the page but when I use `align=center`, some of the contents inside the div are also effected. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CSS (the div must have a width specified as well, see @j08691 comment):

```
div { margin: 0 auto; }
```

`div` should be changed to a more specific selector, such as the ID of your container (`#` denotes ID) or class (`.` denotes class).

Example:

```
#myDivID {}
.myDivClass {}
```

The reason this works is because the rendering engine always tries to optimize and balance the size of any components specified to be `auto`. Here, `margin: 0 auto` is short-hand for:

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Here, the browser doesn't apply any margins on the top and bottom of the `div`, but when it sees that both the left and right margins are set to `auto`, it tries (and succeeds) to make them equal to one another by splitting the remaining space. This results in the `div` being pushed into the center of the page.

Comment: ok, but can you explain how that works so I understand why this is the way to do this?

Comment: Just want to stress to OP that you probably want a more explicit selector such as `#container` unless you want all `DIV` elements centred

Comment: The div needs a width too. Otherwise, being as divs are block level and are 100% wide as their parent, you won't notice any centering effect.

Comment: this would require the width to be set as well to work on all browsers

Comment: still learning html+css. Thanks for the tip on the container, I will give that a try.

Comment: Updated answer with the summary of comments.

Comment: I added an explanation of why this actually works, and is the standard way to achieve this.

Comment: tyvm Matt, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

using pure css:

```
#content {
  width: 10% ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  left: 45%;
  top : 50%;
}
```

or

```
div { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Would this be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this, this should fix your issue

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">'
    dsadkjahdkjasgud
    dbsudbasjdhbasjkdh<br />
    dbsudbasjdhbasjkdh<br />
    <div id="innerCenter">
        dbsudbasjdhbasjkdh<br />
        dbsudbasjdhbasjkdh<br />
        dbsudbasjdhbasjkdh<br />dbsudbasjdhbasjkdh<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer{
        width : 500px;
     background-color:green;

}

#innerCenter{ 
    margin:0 auto;
    width : 50%;
     background-color:red;
}
```

**Note: you can modify the widths as per your layout

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/zKstw/